# C# PictureBox image dont draw complete

Tags: c#

i create a panel and inside this panel i create a picture box. this have no default image. after a function i load a image und put it into this picturebox. the image was bigger as the panel and i want to scroll the image but the image draw only in the first area to see and if i scroll the image dont draw complete. how i can fix this ?

```
        Image TreeImg = new Bitmap(imgPath);
        maletreePictureBox.Width = TreeImg.Width;
        maletreePictureBox.Height = TreeImg.Height;
        maletreePictureBox.Image = TreeImg;
        actionPanel.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(TreeImg.Width, driverTreeImg.Height);
```

[image]

this is the result

Comment: Is it a WinForms app? What's the type of `maletreePictureBox`? What's the type of `actionPanel`? Please [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `.Dock` property of the `maletreePictureBox` to `Fill`.

Also it looks like your `AutoScrollMinSize` `Height` property is incorrect (`driverTreeImg.Height` instead of `TreeImg.Height`)